# Arithmetic operations on dictionary c#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, redis, hashtable

I have this dictionary object as:- `Dictionary<string,string> lstTransList;`

This object has values as `|Key={Id}|Value={|QTY=4|PICKEDUP=2}|`

[image]

now I want to calculate count of records, difference of QTY & PICKEDUP for each record, then summation of QTY, summation PICKEDUP & summation of difference. 
Is there any efficient way of performing these arithmatic operations using LINQ ?

I'm getting count as:-  `int total_transactiondone = lstTransList.Count();`

for summation of QTY I want to split value of dictionary object using Keys as 'QTY' & 'PICKEDUP' but don't know how to use this. Any suggestions ??

Thinking of using something like this :

```
decimal total_tickets = lstTransList.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.Value));
```

**Edit :**

Now I'm using followin approach to achieve this task. Is there any other efficient way to do this ? Please suggest.

```
var lstTransList = objRedis.GetAllEntriesFromHash(strHashey);

DataTable dtTransList = new DataTable();
dtTransList.Columns.Add("TransId");
dtTransList.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(int));
dtTransList.Columns.Add("PickedUp", typeof(int));
dtTransList.Columns.Add("UnPickedUp", typeof(int));

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in lstTransList)
{
    DataRow DR = dtTransList.NewRow();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Key))
    {
        DR[0] = entry.Key;
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Value))
    {
        clsKeyValueParser objKV = new clsKeyValueParser(entry.Value);
        DR[1] = Convert.ToInt32(objKV.strGetValue("QTY", "0"));
        DR[2] = Convert.ToInt32(objKV.strGetValue("PICKEDUP", "0"));
        DR[3] = Convert.ToInt32(DR[1]) - Convert.ToInt32(DR[2]);
    }
    dtTransList.Rows.Add(DR);
}


int total_transactiondone = dtTransList.Rows.Count;
int total_tickets = dtTransList.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<int>(1));
int total_ticketsunpickedup = dtTransList.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<int>(3));
int total_pickeduptransaction = dtTransList.AsEnumerable().Count(row => row.Field<int>(3) == 0);
int total_unpickeduptransaction = dtTransList.AsEnumerable().Count(row => row.Field<int>(3) != 0);
```

Comment: Did that work? Tell us where you're hitting the roadblock, so that we can assist you a bit better... short of having us write the entire code for you, that is.  ;-)

Comment: Why do you use a string as the values instead of a class? It would be so much easier and you do not need to do string operations

Comment: I agree with @Arion.  You should be parsing those strings into classes (preferably custom, but even `Tuple<int,int>` would do) before putting them into the dictionary so you don't have to parse every time you need to do an arithmetic operation on them.

Comment: @Arion : I'm receiving this data from redis. GetAllEntriesFromHash method of RedisClient.

Comment: Imho linq is nice and clear until you have to scroll to read it. Can you solve it with a `foreach`? After trying, you'll at least be able to ask a more specific question.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis as per your suggestions, I tried using foreach loop. I have updated my question, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get a total of the QTY

```
decimal total_tickets_qty = lstTransList.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(Regex.Match(x.Value.Split('|')[1], @"\d+").Value);
```

Total of the PICKEDUP

```
decimal total_tickets_pickedup = lstTransList.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(Regex.Match(x.Value.Split('|')[2], @"\d+").Value));
```

Total of the difference

```
decimal total_tickets = lstTransList.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(Regex.Match(x.Value.Split('|')[1], @"\d+").Value) - Convert.ToDecimal(Regex.Match(x.Value.Split('|')[2], @"\d+").Value));
```

Comment: Hi James thanks for the help. There are some cases where I will have only QTY in Value as '|QTY=2|'. In this case this code will break. Also I want to calculate count of records for which PICKEDUP is 0 or null and count of transactions for which difference between QTY & PICKEDUP is 0.

Comment: It's quite messy to work with a Dictionary<string, string> you are much better off creating a class to store this information with numeric values. Have you tried doing this instead? Doing string manipulations is not a very robust solution.

Comment: I'm getting this data from redis. can you suggest any way to storing this data in classes with numeric values ? Currently I'm using GetAllEntriesFromHash method of RedisClient

Comment: Ok what does GetAllEntriesFromHash return, a string?

Comment: It returns  Dictionary<string, string>